# algebra ,polynomials,functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Determine all real numbers $a$ for which there are non-negative real numbers $x_1,....,x_5$ which satisfy
$$\sum_{k=1}^5 {kx_k}=a,\qquad\sum_{k=1}^5 {k^3x_k}=a^2,\qquad\sum_{k=1}^5 {k^5x_k}=a^3 $$

Answer is given as $a=0,1^2,2^2,...,5^2$

how do I even approach this problem.Any hint would be helpful--thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share what you've tried or thought of so far?

Comment: can we try cauchy schwartz taking 1st and last together-multiplying them--and squaring the middle one                             suppose $a,x_1,...,x_5$ satisfy the  given relations.Then $(x_1+2x_2+...+5x_5)(x_1+2^5x_2+...+5^5x_5)=(x_1+2^3x_2+...+5^3x_5)^2$,since both equal to $a^4$.On the other hand by Cauchy Schwartz inequality we have$(x_1+2x_2+...+5x_5)(x_1+2^5x_2+...+5^5x_5)\ge(\sqrt{{x_1}.{x_1}}+\sqrt{{2x_2}.{2^5x_2}}+...+\sqrt{{5x_5}.{5^5x_5}})^2\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad=(x_1+2^3x_2+....+5^3x_5)^2$

Comment: Nearly! If you take $u_k=\sqrt{kx_k}$ and $v_k=\sqrt{k^5 x_k}$ and put that into Cauchy-Schwarz, you can use the given information. Is the rest of the solution clear?

Comment: Never mind - looks like you're using a different form of CS to me. Can you see what to do next?

Comment: for equality here we need,as per Cauchy Schwartz,a real number $t$  such that $k^5x_k=tkx_k$,for $1\le k\le5$ $\implies kx_k(t-k^4)=0$. how do i proceed from here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the comments nearly got there, but I'll use an answer to clarify things.

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality states that, for real sequences $u_k$ and $v_k$,
$$\left(\sum_k u_k^2\right) \left(\sum_k v_k^2 \right) \ge \left(\sum_k u_k v_k\right)^2$$

with equality iff there exists a non-zero constant $\lambda$ such that for each $k$, $v_k = \lambda u_k$.

Now, since the $x_k$ in this question have to be non-negative, and the $k$ values are positive, we can define $u_k = \sqrt{kx_k}$ and $v_k = \sqrt{k^5 x_k}$. Plugging this in to the inequality,
$$\left(\sum_k kx_k\right) \left(\sum_k k^5 x_k \right) \ge \left(\sum_k k^3 x_k\right)^2$$

which, given the information in the question is
$$a\cdot a^3 \ge a^4$$

But, of course, the two sides are equal; so the equality condition tells us that there is a constant $\lambda$ such that, for each $k=1,2,3,4,5$, $\sqrt{k^5 x_k}=\lambda \sqrt{kx_k}$.

Now, for each $k$, either $x_k=0$ or $x_k>0$. If all $x_k$ are zero, we just get the valid solution $a=0$.

Now assume $x_K>0$ for a particular $K$ we have $x_K>0$. From $\sqrt{K^5 x_K}=\lambda \sqrt{Kx_K}$ we can divide through to leave $\lambda=K^2$. Since the $k^2$ values are all different, this can be true for at most one value $K$, and for $k\neq K$ we must have $x_k=0$. These lead to the possible values $1^2,2^2,3^2,4^2,5^2$ for $a$.